# setOnKeyListener does not exhibit the same behaviour on galaxy s2 as it does on the emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have searched to find a solution to this problem without anyluck.

I have a simpe android app that the user enters a number into one editText (@+id/incBox) field and a given percentage of the that number is automatically placed into another editText (@+id/excBox).

I have implemented a setOnKeyListener for both editText fields, that gets the entered number and does the calculation to update the other field (vice versa).

**This code works fine in the emulator everytime a digit is entered the other editText field is updated . However when running the apk on my samsung galaxy s2 the other field is not updated.** For the other field to be updated *on the phone* you have press Enter on the softkeyboard. What am I missing here? I have even removed the event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP "if" clause to ensure no CANCEL or MULTITOUCH events affect the OnKey listener. How do I get to this to work on the phone?

Another problem that I am experiencing is that after entering a value into a field. Moving to the other field and deleting or pressing enter is quite laggy. Sometimes there is a 0.5 second delay when pressing the backspace button to delete a digit in an already populated field. Is this because of the try catch?

Any help would be appreciated.

this is the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/bground"
>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/inclusive"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/incBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25px"
    android:layout_marginRight="25px"
    android:singleLine="true"
    >
    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20px"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/exclusive" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/excBox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25px"
    android:layout_marginRight="25px"
    android:singleLine="true"
    >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the activity.java

```
public class PercentageCalculatorActivity extends Activity
{

private EditText inclusive;
private EditText exclusive;
DecimalFormat cost = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set Activity Layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the EditText and Button References
    inclusive = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.incBox);
    exclusive = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.excBox);

    //Set KeyListener to ourself
    inclusive.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
    { 
 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
      { 
        try
        {

         double num = Double.parseDouble( inclusive.getText().toString() );

        if ( num > 0)
        {                           
          num = num * 0.25;
        String exc = cost.format(num).toString();
        exclusive.setText(exc);
            }

    // Close the keyboard on enter press                                    if ( keyCode == 66  )                           {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService    (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inclusive.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

            return false;
            }
            catch (Throwable e)
                {
                // set other field to empty if this field is also blank
    exclusive.setText("");
                        return false;
                }            
        }
    });

   exclusive.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
    { 
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        { 
            if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_UP ) 
            { 
                try
                {
                    double num = Double.parseDouble( exclusive.getText().toString() );

                    if ( num > 0)
                    {
                        num = num * 4;
                        String exc = cost.format(num).toString();
                        inclusive.setText(exc);
                    }

                    if ( keyCode == 66  )
                    {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(exclusive.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    }                   

            return false;
                }
                catch (Throwable e)
                {
                    // set other field to empty if this field is also blank 
                                inclusive.setText("");
                    return false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends not on the device but on the keyboard you select. I've run into this before. If you swap out the keyboard for a different one, you'll find that suddenly it starts reacting as you expect. I'm not sure what the cause of this is, but you should give that a try and see if that solves your issue.